# Load event being raised on ResumeLayout(false) when using Infragistic styles

Tags: winforms, load, infragistics, styling

I'm having a problem when using Infragistics styles, the problem is related to the Load event being raised prematurely.

Some context:

- I have a View that is represented by a UserControl
- When I want to show this user control, I create a new instance and add it to a 'host' form that has some extra behaviour non relevant to the problem.

If I don't use styles, the Load event gets raised normally when the Form is shown, which is what I'm expecting, but if I use the `StyleManager.Load` method and load a style then the Load event of the UserControl is raised when doing `ResumeLayout(false)` in one of my panels, which happens in the `InitializeComponents` method in the constructor.

Is this expected behavior? Has anyone experienced the same problem?

---

**edit**:
This seems to be only happening with the Office2007 style, if I use the Office2010 one everything works fine

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty typical Infragistics lossage.  This can happen in general when any code is executed by the constructor that requires the Handle property to be valid.  That causes the CreateHandle method to run, which in turn gets the Load event triggered.  You didn't post a stack trace so there's no way to see what kind of code causes this to happen.  I don't doubt it's Infragistics code.  Get their latest updates, post to their support forum if you want their support.  And try to move code from your Load event handler to the constructor, you only ever need Load if you have code that requires the form size to be known.

Comment: I'll move code from the Load event into other pieces of the form, as is something that I don't need to be there per se..